# Error with imhist in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am a total newbie to matlab and right now I am taking a course on Digital Image Processing. I want to plot the histogram of an image in matlab, which initially seemed simple. However, I always get some error. My code is

---

```
I = imread('C:\Users\Saurabh\Pictures\myimage.jpg');
imhist(I,256)
```

---

The error message is

---

```
Error in ==> img_histogram at 2
imhist(I,256)
```

---

Can some body please explain the error !!

Comment: Is that really the entire error message? Does it not give a description of the error just above the lines you posted?

Comment: Also you might have to convert your image to greyscale before using imhist(). What does size(I) output? If it has a third number then you must convert from RGB to greyscale, try rgb2gray()

Answer (score 1):

This will do regardless color or gray image:

```
bins = 0 : 255;
I_col = reshape(I, [], size(I, 3));
hist(I_col, bins);
```

assuming the values of the image are uint8 in range 0-255